# rospack depends1 error, rosdep version?

Tags: rosdep, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. I follow the directions straight through, everything seems to install perfectly fine. I make my way through the tutorials until I make it to creating an ROS package. (I'd include the link to the tutorial here as the tutorial itself recommends, but I have insufficient karma to do so).

When I try to run the line " $ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials "

It throws an error, telling me that my rosdep version needs to be at least 0.10.40. (Sorry I'm on a different computer right now...I will try to reproduce the full error message and post it here in an edit ASAP).

I check my rosdep version with " $ rosdep --version ", and it tells me that I have 0.10.27 installed.

First, I'm very confused: following the tutorials from installation all the way here lead me to install versions that are already out of date and can't work. Did I miss something? I spend the next few hours trying to install some kind of newer version of rosdep, but I think there is something majorly wrong with my python installations (I have a couple versions and I haven't tightly controlled PYTHONPATH, etc. -- I'm new to python and basically never use it).

So bottom line, 3 questions:

1. Did I miss something in the installation tutorial that would automatically install the proper rosdep version?
2. If not, can the tutorial change to address this issue somehow?
3. Can anyone recommend a tutorial on proper installation (and removing improper installation!) and PYTHONPATH setup for the python version that ROS Hydro needs?

---

EDIT 1: The full error message:

```
$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
ImportError: No module named rosdep2.rospack
ImportError: No module named rosdep2.rospack
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
```

---

EDIT 2: I added to PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2
because I found rosdep2/rospack.py in that folder. Now I get a different error:

```
 $ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        from .installers import InstallerContext, Installer, \
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/installers.py", line 35, in <module>
        from rospkg.os_detect import OsDetect
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
        from .rospack import RosPack, RosStack, \
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 34, in <module>
        from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
        from _elementtree import *
    ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        from .installers import InstallerContext, Installer, \
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/installers.py", line 35, in <module>
        from rospkg.os_detect import OsDetect
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
        from .rospack import RosPack, RosStack, \
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 34, in <module>
        from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
        from _elementtree import *
    ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8
    [rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
```

---

EDIT 3

I tried searching for the EDIT 2 error message. This is a python problem that is described as "two pythons compiled with different numbers of bytes for unicode characters." Best explanation I've found: http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/16871799/trying-to-import-a-module-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs4-decodeutf8.

So I recompiled my python 2.7.6 with --enabled-unicode=ucs4 and the error has now changed to

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyLong_AsInt
```

What options were the ROS modules compiled with? I apparently need to manually set up my python 2.7.6 with these options.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159416/rospack-depends1-error,-rosdep-version?/) by [mechanicalmanb](https://answers.ros.org/users/15411/mechanicalmanb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-05-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-05-01**:
The latest rosdep version is 0.10.27. Can you please post your exact error message? I guess the error message just said "at least 0.10.4".

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-01**:
What instructions are you following? If you follow these instructions http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu line for line it should work fine.

For us to help you more. You need to provide a lot more details about what steps you are following.

**Comment by [mechanicalmanb](https://answers.ros.org/users/15411/mechanicalmanb/) on 2014-05-01**:
Those are the exact instructions I used. Line by line.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-01**:
You're doing things that are much too complicated. You must have state on the system which is not standard. I notice /usr/local in your tracebacks suggesting you've installed custom modules. Are there other modifications to the system?

**Comment by [mechanicalmanb](https://answers.ros.org/users/15411/mechanicalmanb/) on 2014-05-02**:
I had installed python 2.7.6 and python 3.4 with default options before attempting to install ROS hydro. I agree with you, I think that there are some serious low level conflicts going on here that are beyond my skill. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and installed ROS Indigo first, which works fine so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the exact same error after installing Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. All I have done so far is follow exactly the instructions for installing ROS Indigo and the first few pages of the tutorial.

```
$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials 
ImportError: No module named rosdep2.rospack
ImportError: No module named rosdep2.rospack
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
```

I ran rosdep --version and I have 0.10.30. I also ran rosdep update but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The only other program that had been installed on my Ubuntu distribution was the anaconda ipython distribution. This seemed to be what was causing the problem. I ran $ rm -rf ~/anaconda to remove it and now

```
$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials 
std_msgs
rospy
roscpp
```

is function. So the problem was that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDZX4ooRsWs.

---

Originally posted by [messidona](https://answers.ros.org/users/20283/messidona/) with karma: 56 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haifei](https://answers.ros.org/users/23965/haifei/) on 2015-09-23**:
Thank you for your answer, you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pip install rosdep
solved it for me

---

Originally posted by [M_Allam](https://answers.ros.org/users/28027/m_allam/) with karma: 73 on 2016-09-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samuelwg](https://answers.ros.org/users/29317/samuelwg/) on 2017-02-09**:
Yeah me too.  I didn't want to uninstall anaconda so I think this is the way to go

**Comment by [philglau](https://answers.ros.org/users/6271/philglau/) on 2017-03-17**:
Ditto. I'm not interested in giving up anaconda as a "fix". First I used "which pip" to make sure my pip was the anaconda version and then using 'pip install rosdep' resolved this for me as well.

**Comment by [hafizas101](https://answers.ros.org/users/44506/hafizas101/) on 2019-09-11**:
$ pip install rosdep solved the problem for me on ubuntu 18.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-11**:
You should not install packages with `pip` if there is a Debian package available. It would overlay the Debian package and therefore you would get newer updates so will likely run into problems in the future.